# What is default password for Jupyter created on google's data proc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

I set data proc using the steps in link here

https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/jupyter-notebook

But my jyputer keep asking for password

[image]

I didn't set any password.

I tried my google account password that doesn't work

I ran  `../root$ sudo grep -ir password`
and get following, so that confirmed no password is set

```
.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py:## Hashed password to use for web authentication.
.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py:#  The string should be of the form type:salt:hashed-password.
.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py:#c.NotebookApp.password = u''
.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py:#  Only used when no password is enabled.
.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3668.json:  "password": false,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the initialization action just installs from latest using `conda install jupyter`, this appears to have been caused by a recent upstream change, specifically upgrading the `notebook` component from `4.2.3` to `4.3.0` causing [token-based auth to be turned on by default](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/commit/7fa5d5a1be147e9c8e14f61a2f4b3c0db1e2c00b). A recent cluster I deployed a couple weeks ago using the out-of-the-box init action didn't have the same login you're seeing; the design of the init action is to let Google Compute Engine firewalls be your layer of defense and the SSH tunnel being your secure connection, rather than relying on various third-party implementations of auth from the different Hadoop/Spark tools and web UIs.

The solution will be to add a line to [setup-jupyter-kernel.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/jupyter/internal/setup-jupyter-kernel.sh#L25):

```
echo "c.NotebookApp.token = u''" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

to disable jupyter-side authentication altogether and revert to the behavior a couple weeks ago. Note that if you want to do this yourself you'll have to fiddle with the `INIT_ACTIONS_REPO` and `INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH` settings in `jupyter.sh` which may take some getting used to if you haven't been customizing it already. We'll try to push a fix as soon as possible and once that's done you should be able to use the out-of-the-box init action without causing the login screen again.

If you already have a cluster running, you can disable the auth for your jupyter server by running that manually as root after SSH'ing into the master:

```
sudo su
killall -9 jupyter-notebook
echo "c.NotebookApp.token = u''" >> ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
/dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/internal/launch-jupyter-kernel.sh
```

Alternatively, if you do want to keep the new default token-authorization approach, the jupyter server actually logs a generated token to `/var/log/jupyter_notebook.log`; look for a line stating `The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8123/?token=[some-token-string-here]`; that token string can be plugged in to the password field or in the URL parameter as it shows.

EDIT: The fix has [now been committed](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/81) into Dataproc's init action repository and synced to `gs://dataproc-initialization-actions`. Deployments out-of-the-box once again work without an extra login page in the Jupyter UI.

A new metadata option has also been added if you do want to specify a token which Jupyter also allows to be used in the `password` field, with key `JUPYTER_AUTH_TOKEN`. Use it as follows only if you want a login page requesting your specified token (no metadata keys are necessary if you just want the old behavior of no login page):

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create \
    --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
    --metadata JUPYTER_AUTH_TOKEN=foobarbaz
```

Then your login password will be `foobarbaz`.

Comment: Thanks!! I literally spent 7+ hours trying different combinations (including different machines and zones) thinking why it was working before and not working anymore. Going to try this now.

Comment: Yeah, this also slipped under the radar on the Dataproc side, appreciate your bringing this up! I also added a paragraph at the end for another alternative if you keep the token flow and want to grep out the generated password/token from /var/log/jupyter_notebook.log. In general though the default guidance using an SSH tunnel and keep firewalls closed is still ideal for this use case and doesn't require jupyter-enforced auth.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! it worked, I like the alternate approach. I really needed it for my final ML project.

Comment: Please update this thread when the fix is pushed. Last question, is it possible to run my local jupyter notebook by pointing to dataproc cluster?  For example, I currently run my notebook using this ```$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --master spark://<my-home-cluster>:7077``` can I use Google GCP somehow instead of my-home-cluster?

Comment: Once again thanks for a prompt response, you made a difference between a solid A and C for my course :)

Comment: To answer your question about running a local notebook, unfortunately it would be nontrivial to do this currently, though theoretically possible. It would require carefully opening ports to your home connection without opening them up to the whole internet, including ports where low-level akka communication may be occurring between a SparkContext and a Spark AppMaster running on the Dataproc cluster. There are also known issues with hostname resolution since the external connection will be dialing in via external IP, while on the cluster internal IPs and hostnames are used.

Comment: FYI, the fix has been committed and synced, everything should work normally with default settings again.

Comment: Right, this "fix" was dataproc-specific. Upstream Jupyter installation has more reason to keep the auth-token default behavior, since people may be installing on networks that don't have firewall protection of the jupyter port

Answer (score 1):

When you dont set any password you can login with the your server credentials where it is installed.